# Not understanding this ARM snippet

Tags: floating-point, arm

I'm working on decompiling an ARMv7 binary by hand, and I've come across a few instructions that I don't totally understand. It looks like this:

```
VLDR        S15, [R3]
VCMPE.F32   S15, #0.0
VMRS        APSR_nzcv, FPSCR
BMI         .next
```

R3 prior to this points to an entry in a float array.
I understand it's comparing that float with 0.0F, but I can't tell what else it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

If the comparison of `[R3]` with `0.0f` is negative, the control jumps to `.next` - otherwise, it continues on.

See the comment following each instruction:

```
VLDR        S15, [R3]           ; load [R3] to S15
VCMPE.F32   S15, #0.0           ; compare s15 with 0.0F
VMRS        APSR_nzcv, FPSCR    ; move FP flags to ARM core flags [N,Z,C,V]
BMI         .next               ; branch if result is negative i.e. N=1
```

See documentation:

- [VLDR](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0802a/Bcfcdfdd.html)
- [VCMPE](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0802a/Bcfejdgg.html)
- [VMRS](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0802a/Bcfbdihi.html)

Comment: But what does it mean for the result to be negative? If S15 - 0.0F is negative?

Comment: @MarinaTerry: Yes, See more details in the [docs](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0802a/Bcfejdgg.html).